# How to reverse a circular single linked list

Tags: c++, c, reverse, circular-list

It's easy to reverse a single linked list, the follow code works fine.

```
void reverse_list (SLINK list)
{
    SLINK tmp = list->next; 
    NODE *cur = NULL;
    list->next = NULL;
    for (; NULL != tmp;)    
    {
            cur = tmp;
            tmp = tmp->next;
            cur->next = list->next;
            list->next = cur;
    }
}
```

How to reverse a circular single linked list? I adjust the code to this

```
SLINK reverse_list (SLINK rear)
{
    NODE *tag = rear->next;
    SLINK tmp = rear->next;
    NODE *cur = NULL;
    rear->next = NULL;
    for (; NULL != tmp; )
    {
        cur = tmp;
        tmp = tmp->next;
        cur->next = rear;
        rear->next = cur;
    }
    rear = tag;
    return rear;
}
```

but it does not work, and I thought after run this function, The circular list would be non-circular, actually, after dump it, I found it is still a circular list.
It must be that I make a wrong logic in it, please show me right.

Comment: Google it you can find dozens of good sites. Find here [algorithm and program to reverse circular linked list](https://codeforwin.org/2018/11/c-program-to-reverse-a-circular-linked-list.html)

Answer (score 1):

Like Amit, I can't quite understand the idea behind your code... But from a purely logical point of view, if you already know how to turn a regular list around, your best option is to copy all of the elements of your circular list into a new, regular list with a 'for', stopping when the first element is equal to the current one, and then turning the new list around with your code to reverse single linked lists.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you say that the code for reversing a single linked list is fine. To me it looks wrong. The line 
   cur->next = list->next;
wouldn't it set the next pointer of the second node to NULL, given that you have already set list->next to NULL outside the loop? Shouldn't it be going to the first node?

And why did you expect a reversal of a circular linked list to result in a linear list? The reversal would just cause a clockwise to anticlockwise (or vice-versa) shift in link directions, if you were to draw the circular list on a piece of paper.

The only logic change between circular list reverse and liner list reverse would be that you would not set the next pointer to NULL for the first node in case of circular linked list

Comment: the list I test is with a header,the line cur->next = list->next; would set the next pointer of the first node to NULL

Answer (score 0):

here is one method;

```
node *toggle(node *start){

        node *p=NULL;
        node *c=start;
        node *ne=NULL;
        node *e;
        int f=0;
        do{
            ne=c->next;
            c->next=p;
            p=c;
            if(f==0){
                e=p;
                f=1;
            }
            c=ne;
        }while(c!=start);

        start=p;
        e->next=p;
return start;
```

}

Comment: well i used three pointers , p which points out to previous element, c which points to current element, and ne which points to next element,
we know in circular list last element points to start; so i just make current element point to previous  element , then make the previous =current  and current=next until we current return backs to start=which is now the last element, since previous is one behind the current it becomes the first element;so i simply make start=p and e= which is last element now point to p;

Answer (score 0):

```
void reverse()
{
    // reverse procedure same as reversing a
    // singly linked list
    struct node *p, *q, *r;
    p = first; // first is head node
    q = NULL;
    r = NULL;
    do
    {
        q = p->next;
        p->next = r;
        r = p;
        p = q;
    } while (p != first);

    // adjutsing the links so as to make the
    // last node point to the first node
    first->next = r;
    first = r;
}
```